# use datatables and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I have a php code that currently creates a html file from a txt file and updates every two hours on my website. I would like to convert it to data tables. Is there an easy way to link to the txt file using jquery, data tables and php?

This is what I am making: http://live.datatables.net/eduvin/edit#javascript,html,live

The file that I use is a txt file that converts to HTML using php. The PHP is updated on a server every two hours. I would like to replace all of this just with the jquery data table and update that every two hours. The update program I use is windows task scheduler in Windows server 2003. Is this possible? And if so what would be the best way of doing so.

This is my PHP code:

```
 <?php
 set_time_limit(0);
 function csv_split($line,$delim=',',$removeQuotes=true) { 
 #$line: the csv line to be split 
 #$delim: the delimiter to split by 
 #$removeQuotes: if this is false, the quotation marks won't be removed from the fields 
 $fields = array(); 
 $fldCount = 0; 
 $inQuotes = false; 
 for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($line); $i++) { 
   if (!isset($fields[$fldCount])) $fields[$fldCount] = ""; 
   $tmp = substr($line,$i,strlen($delim)); 
   if ($tmp === $delim && !$inQuotes) { 
       $fldCount++; 
       $i += strlen($delim)-1; 
   } else if ($fields[$fldCount] == "" && $line[$i] == '"' && !$inQuotes) { 
       if (!$removeQuotes) $fields[$fldCount] .= $line[$i]; 
       $inQuotes = true; 
   } else if ($line[$i] == '"') { 
       if ($line[$i+1] == '"') { 
           $i++; 
           $fields[$fldCount] .= $line[$i]; 
       } else { 
           if (!$removeQuotes) $fields[$fldCount] .= $line[$i]; 
           $inQuotes = false; 
       } 
   } else { 
       $fields[$fldCount] .= $line[$i]; 
   } 
} 
 return $fields; 
} 
$html_body = 'HTML goes here'
$fp=fopen("csv/inventory4.html",'w');
$write=fputs($fp,$html_body,strlen($html_body));
$i=0;
$content = file("webinvt.txt");
foreach($content as $line)
 {
$l=csv_split($line);
if(!strstr($l[11],"SET"))
{
if($i==10)
{
    $tmp = '</table>
   <table width="100%"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">      <tbody><tr>
     ';
    $write=fputs($fp,$tmp,strlen($tmp));
    $i=0;
}
$onhand = (int)$l[15];
$committed = (int)$l[16];
$avail = $onhand - $committed;
$wcdate = substr($l[23],4);
$eastdate = substr($l[19],4);

if(strstr($l[1],"DISC"))
{
    $html_body ='<tr style="color:#FF0000 ">
    <td width="12%" >'.$l[0].'</td>
    <td width="30%" >'.$l[1].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[12].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$avail.'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[17].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[18].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$eastdate.'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[21].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[22].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$wcdate.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
else
{
    $html_body ='<tr>
    <td width="12%" >'.$l[0].'</td>
    <td width="30%" >'.$l[1].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[12].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$avail.'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[17].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[18].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$eastdate.'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[21].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$l[22].'</td>
    <td width="8%" >'.$wcdate.'</td>
    </tr> 
   ';
}

 $write=fputs($fp,$html_body,strlen($html_body));
 $i++;
}
}

$html_body='<tr>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
<td scope="col"></td>
 </tr>

 </table>
 </body>
 </html>';

$write=fputs($fp,$html_body,strlen($html_body));

fclose($fp);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at this the wrong way.  Why not have the php look into the database and render the page each time?   This is what most websites do and there are plenty of examples out there.

No need to have the intermediary text file.

The php file could remain as is, instead of opening and reading a csv file you would open and read the database.  You can then put the results into the fields array, so the rest of the php file does not need to change.

This is a great reference to connecting to the database:

As an example here is some code:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM items");

$res->data_seek(0);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fields[0] = $row['field1'];
    $fields[1] = $row['field2'];
    $fields[2] = $row['field3'];
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I have no idea how to go about getting rid of the txt file since it contains all my data.

Comment: Do you have an example?  It should be pretty easy.

Comment: Thanx for the advice. I have no experience in creating SQL databases. How would I convert my text file to one? And if I just create an SQL database, I do not believe I need the rest of the PHP, since all the styling is done in my css file anyway.